# Android Relative Layout - doesn't work like I want

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying this now days and it still doesn't work. I read lots of tutorials about the Relative layout but I still can't do it. Please give me an idea, what I can do. I want a simple layout like in the picture.![enter image description here][1]

edit: Looks like I can't upload images ... :(

Its a layout for a simple quiz App with these widgets below each other. A ProgressBar, a TextView for a question, 4 Buttons for the answers. The TextView should take all the place the other widgets don't need. The Button should be always at the end.

I tried with alignParentTop, Bottom, nested LinearLayouts and it still doesn't work. What can I do? It would be REALLY REALLY great to have an idea? Thanks a lot!

Good idea: I uploaded the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dC2z.jpg

Here is the actual code. (I edited it about 20x times)

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/answerProgressBar"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdownTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/answerProgressBar"
        android:text="00:00:00" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/questionImageView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/countdownTextView"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/answerProgressBar"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/questionImageView"
        android:text="jfh rhguijfhg fhge hugutbh r rut hruteruzt dkjfh uzdt ggu zguzg zuh ftz huuh rh grhtughrtu thiohjriwetk lkj rgjrjkrjek"
        android:textSize="22dp" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answert1Button"
            style="@style/answerButton"
            android:text="answer 1" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer2Button"
            style="@style/answerButton"
            android:text="answer 2" />


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer3Button"
            style="@style/answerButton"
            android:text="answer 3" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/answer4Button"
            style="@style/answerButton"
            android:text="answer 4 Butto d uzrr rd drtd gzugt ffzft drtn" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Upload your screenshot to someplace like imgur.com and link it in your post.

Answer (score 0):

With `RelativeLayout` it's the *easiest way* to position your widgets to the screen. **However**, it may take some time until you master it. Since if you're designing your layout with Graphic Tool, it will be harder.

Try editing it in **XML Text**. Make sure to read [this Android Dev Tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html) on all the options you can access with using `RelativeLayout`.
I am sure you did check it, but I'm also quite sure that you were only searching for the obvious solutions. Sometimes, some not so obvious options will lead you to your goal - so be patient and try to do it from scratch with help of the tutorial.

Otherwise you could also use `FrameLayout` which divides your screen into several frames. **BUT**, again, it might complicate things for you in your App.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I read the tutorial again and again, but still didn't get it. Now I uploaded the image and the code. Maybe you have an idea?

Comment: Sorry dude, but from your code all I can see it that you really didn't read any of the tutorials. You don't even position your buttons in ANY way. Go and check some positioning actions for Android Widgets  like `android:layout_margin` etc. There are plenty more. I notice you didn't use any of those on your buttons.

Answer (score 0):

First, to make it easier, remove countdownTextView and questionImageView, and let's try.

I think you need to place *layout_alignParentTop* attribute with the ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/answerProgressBar"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
```

And put all Buttons in a vertical LinearLayout with *layout_alignParentBottom*:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/answerButtons"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/answerButton1"
        style="@style/answerButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="answer1" />

    (...)

</LinearLayout>
```

And at last, the TextView has to have both *layout_below* and *layout_above* attributes with setting *layout_height="match_parent"*:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/questionTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="R.id.answerProgressBar"
    android:layout_above="R.id.answerButtons"
    android:text="blah blah blah" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! In AndroidStudio I can't use     android:layout_above because it says: Error:(35, 31) No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_above' with value '@id/antwortButtonsLinearLayout'). - But it works a bit when not using the layout_above command

Comment: It should be caused of *@id/antwortButtonsLinearLayout* but *layout_above*. You should specify an id for *layout_above* as *R.id.answerButtonsLinearLayout*.